# C++ Visual Studio 2017 after update cannot open source files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

3 of my includes are marked red as seen on the screenshot. VS adnotation says "cannot open source file " but when I rightclick on, for example, `#include <windows.h>` and use "Open Document windows.h" document is opened so VS has access to this library and project compiles and works. The same goes for `#include <d3d10.h>` and `#include <d3dx10.h>`. When creating variables like `D3DXVECTOR3 Pos`, D3DXVECTOR3 is marked red as well and VS adnotation says "identifier D3DXVECTOR3 is undefinied".

[image: Screenshot of code in VS]

How can i repair it? I tried to repair and reinstall VS using VS installer.

Comment: I'm having a lot of issues with vs2017 too. Try rebuilding or clean and then build. Or remove the entire hidden .vs folder in the solution folder (while vs is closed) then reopen and rebuild

Comment: I've had my VS-installation broken after updates multiple times. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: @Neijwiert It helped, thanks a lot!